# javascript validation

Tags: javascript, validation

I am using a regular expression validation to validate my form using javascript.
my pattern is

```
/^[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9_]*\\.{0.1}[a-zA-Z0-9_]*/
```

is this pattern correct for validating "not starting from number","only 1 `'.'` allowed and then text"?

wat can i use in javascript for validation?? something like `preg_match` func of **php**.

I m not familiar with regular expressions so help me and give sum func to do this for me.
i tried to use `regexp` object but cant get result from .exec,test function.

Comment: I'm not quite clear on what you want to achieve with the regular expression, but I advise you to check out http://www.regextester.com/ which I use to verify my "regexes", as well as take a look at http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html, as there are probably a few character classes, that will make it easier to read your expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the regexp looks good. Require 1 char, followed by 0..inf char, number or _, followed by an optional dot, followed by 0..inf char, number or _.

You have one syntacticaly error though. Replace the `{0.1}` with `{0,1}`.

You can then use the `.test()` function and pass it a string to test.

```
var a = "bb";
var r = /^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*\.{0,1}[a-zA-Z0-9_]*/;
r.test(a);
```

returns true.

Comment: hey thanks for your support but..this validation pattern not working perfectly...i used '$' at the end then its working perfectly..May i know what is the use of '$' at the end..i used it eariler but didnt asked y it is used..

Comment: the first 'plus' is unnecessary

Comment: `$` marks the end of a string. Thus, if you include it in your regexp it will require that the string ends there. This is helpful if you want to specify specific lengths as well etc.